# Owning a colony on the same continent as the capital?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

As Ireland I have moved my capital to North America. There is a colonial nation created by Scotland (Scottish California). Will annexing Scotland result in owning a colony on the same continent as my capital?
Or will the territories of Scottish California be annexed? => I will have to core them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you'll get the CN. Which is just as well - they can colonize for you to better shut off NA from those pesky spaniards. Eventually, once you're far, far bigger then they are, as long as you followed a policy of taxing the hell out of them (raising tariffs in events), you'll be able to give them independence and conquer them.

Comment: I am pretty late into the game, so the only possible colonies are in the middle of North America and only I can access them. It would be nice that at the end (in 30 years) all of the N.Am. provinces are under my direct control and not under a colony of mine. So most probably, I will have to annex that territory first and then annex Scotland. Or annex Scotland, and after release Scottish California, declare war and annex them.

Comment: So, yeah.. I've annexed Scotland, and Scottish California is now a colony on the same continent. I'll have to free it and annex it to have the territory under my control. They're not a vassal so I can't diplo-annex.